# Give Parameter to Regex in Java

Tags: java

I try to parse log file:

```
'Del   username /PART="deneme" /ROLE="VR_ANALYST" /TYPE="C" /CAPABILITY="S" /ADD' (S)
'Del   Batu /PART="_PROJECT" /ROLE="VR_AUTHOR" /TYPE="R" /CAPABILITY="S" /ADD' (S)
```

RULE => *'Del input ........ /ROLE="input2" .......*

`input` and `input2` will given from user.
In this sentence :

- `username`: should be a parameter (input from user)
- `VR_ANALYST`: should be a parameter (input from user)
- `'Del`: must be in the regex (the first four letters must be `'Del`)
- `/ROLE=""`: must be in the regex

1)Regex should start with 'Del 
2)continue with first input 
3)some other strings 
4)/ROLE=" 
5)second input 
6)" 
7)continue with other strings

I have nearly no knowledge about regex but I try to do :

```
'Del parameter \"*"\ (/ROLE=") parameter2 (") \*
```

Could you please give some advice how can create a regex of this sentence and use my paramters in this regex.

Comment: What do you mean by 'should be a parameter' and 'must be in the regex'? Do you want to *extract* values from the input? Please describe the rules to identify the values in the input. And please include more that one line of input.

Comment: I am editting my question.

Comment: should be a parameter means that parts of regex will be given from user so they are inputs(args[0],args[1]).
1)Regex should start with 'Del
2)continue with first input 
3)some other strings
4)/ROLE="
5)second input 
6)"
7)continue with other strings

Comment: Try to build regex that matches the input *without* parameters. Then change your code to build the regex *with* parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1.About regex i'll suggest You some of a online regex checker like (http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and just learn a little, its pretty simple ;)

2.If u want to add Your parameters to the regex u can use 
`replace(oldChar, newChar)` on string that contains regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this REGEX..

```
^'Del\s*parameter.*/ROLE="parameter2".*
```